# How do we fetch the list of all content types refererencing a particular taxonomy vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to delete a taxonomy vocabulary but before doing that, I want to know if there is any content type with a field referencing a taxonomy vocabulary.

My first thought was using a view, but that would only list content. Unless it can display the type and group by the type, it would not be the best solution.

Comment: That info is stored in the config table in the DB. You could do a quick query for something like `SELECT  *  FROM config WHERE data  LIKE '%<your_vocab_machine_name>%' AND name LIKE 'field.field%'`  that should bring back any fields that mention your vocab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check from UI then maybe you can try the Field list page (`/admin/reports/fields`) for checking which all the places have the required taxonomy field has been referenced/used.

Comment: That page only lists all your fields. Due to a field can be an entity reference, you won't know if you are pointing at a taxonomy, node, etc. Even if you'd know that only uses taxonomy, you can't say wich taxonomy.